# New Mac: how to stop iCloud Drive from downloading locally every single fle?

Tags: icloud, storage

I have a new Macbook and I am having a problem with the iCloud Drive.

The Macbook is downloading locally every single file that I have on iCloud, but that amounts to over 200 Gb of data and it is going to take forever, besides using up a lot of space.

**My question: How can I choose only a few folders to download locally?**

After the file or folder is downloaded, I have the option to right-click on it and choose "Remove Download". However, I would prefer to not have to download it in the first place.

Comment: Did you check the System Preferences for iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

You can have macOS store your infrequently used documents, full-resolution photos and videos, and all messages and attachments in iCloud and retrieve them to your MacBook only when needed to save on storage space on your MacBook.

As described in the "[Optimize storage space on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/system-information/optimize-storage-space-sysp4ee93ca4/mac)" Apple Support article for macOS Monterey, go to Apple Sign (on the top left) -> About This Mac -> Storage -> Manage and click on the "Store in iCloud" button and activate any of the "Desktop and Documents", "Photos", and "Messages" categories in the window to open as per necessary and click on "Store in iCloud" again to close the window. Also, make sure the "Optimize Mac Storage" option is activated in the System Preferences -> Apple ID -> iCloud page as shown in the "[Set up iCloud features on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-icloud-on-your-mac-mh36834/12.0/mac/12.0)" Apple Support article.

If there are folders you wish to make sure they are downloaded onto your MacBook, right click on any of them in Finder and select "Download Now".

Comment: Note though if you do not keep the full documents and original photos ie you choose to Optimize you cannot take a full backup from your mac and have to rely on iCloud being the only place where there is a copy. (So if you accidentally delete a file make sure you restore it quickly - I think 30 days)

Comment: Hi, Alper! Thx for your help! Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. There is no way to set the configuration as "open as per necessary".  Also, I think I wasn't clear in my question. I still want to locally download some of my folders, I just don't want to have to download all of them in the first place. "Optimize Mac Storage" is activated.

Comment: I did not mean that there was a configuration option as "open per necessary" in the window to open when you click on the "Store in Cloud" button described above. There are three category options in that window which are "Desktop and Documents", "Photos", and "Messages" and you can activate any of them as per necessary. Changes to iCloud-related settings sometimes take time to have full impact. Give it a few days after changing settings as described above and see what happens. The "Download Now" action described in my answer's last paragraph should make the related folders downloaded locally.